# scp not working

Tags: java, ssh, scp

I need to copy a file from remote machine(which is using Windows OS) to my machine(It also uses Windows OS) using ssh in java.So i used JSch sample code exec to do this work.In this i gave scp command to copy files.but i always get -1 as returned value.Even i used ScpFrom sample code which also didnt work in my case.In some case It returned

```
Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.
exit-status: -1
```

other cases (i.e) used different slashes or path and it returned only

```
exit-status: -1
```

scp command used

```
scp -f user@ipadress:\user\folder\file.txt \user1\folder2
```

user-username of remotemachine

i even changed the slashes to forward one or with double slash.All things failed.

**does freesshd server supports SCP?**

Could any one help me in figure out the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Windows machines got something installed to support scp ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the output from executing the jsch command? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902386/how-to-read-jsch-command-output) for an example. More logging will help debug this.

Comment: @AviramSegal i have installed freesshd server to support scp

Comment: @MartinFoot i tried it.but no output is coming except exit status -1

Comment: Have you tried to run this command in terminal?

Comment: do i need to work it in windows terminal or ssh terminal? i tried it in windows terminal and says scp command not recognized.i could not find any ssh terminal with freesshd server.

Comment: If you have access to a linux box or OS X, try running scp from a terminal window to the windows box that has freesshd server on it to confirm freesshd is working. Also try plain ssh into the same box if previous fails.

Comment: @sdjuan i dont have access to a linux box or OS X. i did some googling about scp in freesshd server.some says it has scp others says it doesnt have.so i got confused and removed it i am trying openssh.it is working fine there.so thank you for taking time and trying to help me.if i had some time i will try to check out the soln provided by you and will tell about the o/p.and also sorry not to post that i had moved away from that.